# How to tie a docker container to a specific IP address for outgoing connections?

Tags: docker, networking

I have a set of Docker containers (C1, C2, C3) running on a Debian system.

The system has several IP addresses we'll call IP1, IP2, IP3

Right now all containers run on the same Docker network (DN) and, without any configuration from my part, do all outside communication with the machine's first IP (IP1).

I would like to know how to set something like this:

- All containers can talk to each other on the main Docker network (DN), as it is now.
- When C3 initiates an outgoing connection (calling an outside REST API for example), I would like C3 to initiate that connection through IP3.

How can this be achieved?

The goal here is to have several containers accessing external services that do have IP based rate limits. I can't do all the calls on a single IP and need to spread them across several IP addresses. However, I still need to retain the ability for containers to talk to one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you do this by adding rules to the `POSTROUTING` chain of your `nat` table. If you want to map each container to a *specific* outbound address, you would do something like:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s <container-c1-address> -j SNAT --to-source IP1
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s <container-c2-address> -j SNAT --to-source IP2
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s <container-c3-address> -j SNAT --to-source IP3
```

Note that we're *inserting* these rules at the top of the `POSTROUTING` chain to ensure that they come **before** the default `MASQUERADE` rule that Docker adds to the chain.

The problem with the above solution is that you'll need to re-create the rules every time you re-create your containers. An alternative solution is to probabilistically select an outbound address for any traffic coming from the default Docker network.  That might look something like:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.33 -j SNAT --to-source IP1
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.33 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.33 -j SNAT --to-source IP3
```

For each outbound packet, this would select one of your ip addresses with about 33% probability.

If your default Docker network is something other than 172.17.0.0/16 you would update your rules as necessary.